# Can I reverse a sentence like this?

Tags: grammar, meaning

The original sentence is:

> When we came to the chasm, we saw that the only way across was an old rope bridge.

Can I say the following instead?

> When we came to the chasm, we saw an old bridge that was the only way across.

Comment: They are both grammatical, but they have slightly different meanings. In the first you are seeing the fact that there is only one way of across (which is an old rope bridge). In the second, you are seeing an old rope bridge (which is the only way across). Each sentence places the emphasis on something different being seen.

Comment: Also, the second sentence doesn't necessarily mean you did or didn't know at the time that the bridge was the only crossing. It makes sense whether it was obvious there was no other way, or whether you only found that out later.